# css move a string two space to the left

Tags: css

I have a ul with two li.

```
<ul>
  <li class="first">$2.00</li>
  <li class="second">- $4.00</li>
</ul>
```

right now when the print their not properly align. what I want to do is move the second class two the left two spaces so both of the dollar sign symbols align vertically this is my codepen.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/candoa/pen/PNRGoj?editors=1100#anon-login)

Comment: I think something went wrong with your codepen link.

Comment: Tell exactly what you want to achieve with proper codepen link. Mention the exact scenario.

Comment: Sorry I realized that after I posted the question. my codepen is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would specify the sign in a class like this:

```css
.negative::before {
  position: absolute;   
  content:"-";
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first positive">$2.00</li>
  <li class="second negative">$4.00</li>
</ul>
```

It would be especially convenient as most accounting applications are expected to show negative numbers differently (depending on the country's usages).

If necessary, it's possible to use JavaScript to automatically set the "negative" class:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"), function(e){
  if (/^-\$\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(e.textContent)){
       e.className = "negative";
       e.textContent = e.textContent.replace(/-/,'');
  }
});
```

```css
.negative::before {
  position: absolute;   
  content:"-";
  left: 40px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>$2.00</li>
  <li>-$4.00</li>
</ul>
```